# How can I make a function containing NA work accurate?

Tags: r, loops, vector, statistics

I created a function that adds the square of numbers in vectors, but I can't get the correct result when one of the variables is NA. How can I make this work ? Thank you already

```
sos=function(){
example=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA)
newExample=c()
for (i in 1:10){
  count=0
  count=count+example[i]^2
  newExample=append(newExample,count)
  }
print(sum(newExample))
}
```

Comment: `print(sum(newExample, na.rm=TRUE))`?

Comment: ```print(sum(newExample, na.rm=TRUE))``` worked. Thank you. @jay.sf